# How to notify the service provider to block/unblock the incoming SMS programatically in android?

Tags: android, sms, service-provider

I want to notify the service provider to block and unblock the incoming SMS. Is it possible to do this programtically?

Answer (score 1):

Your asking a service to automatically notify the service provider to block or unblock sms from a number. NO that is not possible. Though it is possible for you to specify that number and send it to the service provider.

Next alternative is to block the sms from your mobile phone itself. This would be operator independent and would only hide the message from the blocked number.